# sever side code for upload.php

Tags: php, .net

code for capture in phonegap api. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#Capture.
what is the meaning of `"http://my.domain.com/upload.php"` in upload file function.what concept is used in server side for uploading video and audio from phonegap

please provide the code for upload.php in phonegap api(capture) to upload video and audio

Comment: have you tried it already? can you post some code?

Comment: am not trying in server side.am trying in phone Gap please tell me the concept for developing server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since phonegap's [File Transfer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) does an HTTP post, at it's most basic, this should get you started:

```
<?php
   $new_image_name = "namethisimage.jpg";
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/myuploads/".$new_image_name);
?>
```

More reference here:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: You asked for upload.php, that's what I gave you...  If you want to do it with .net, it would be helpful if you had asked that in your original question.